# How to get total amount of reviews belongs to one category? [Magento 1.9]

Tags: magento-1.9, category, seo, review, rich-snippets

I am trying to generate SEO rich data in Magento for a category or listing page. I just don't understand how can I get the total amount of reviews for a that category.

I don't want to slow down the category page.

Is it possible to get that by directly executing an SQL command?

Please help me :(

Comment: Rich data in Category view

Comment: It is different based on which version you are using and you've tagged it with both for some reason.  Are you on Magento 1 or 2?

Comment: I have mentioned in title magento 1.9. Your help will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

In the main product-list template, you will see the collection populated with `$_productCollection=$this->getLoadedProductCollection();` somewhere near the top of file.  Depending on whether [you are using a custom theme](https://inchoo.net/magento/creating-a-new-magento-theme/), the file's location may be different, but the filepath will be something like this:

`[magento-root]/app/design/frontend/<your-theme>/<your-subtheme>/template/catalog/product/list.phtml`

**Note:**  This is extending the default template, located at

`[magento-root]/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/list.phtml`

There are a few things that you could experiment with, but basically, you'd loop through the product-collection and use `$_product->getRatingSummary()` and possibly `$_product->getReviewSummaryHtml()` to get what some in-depth information.

Luckily, the default template already looks for a review, so you really just need to add a counter and/or custom logic in the two places that you see `<?php if($_product->getRatingSummary()): ?>`

So, if all you are looking for is the count. Add the following to the top of your file:

`$reviewCount = 0;`

..and there are two places (list and grid mode) that you would find a place to increment it.  In the simplest example, you would replace this:

```
<?php if($_product->getRatingSummary()): ?>
<?php echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product) ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

with this:

```
<?php if($_product->getRatingSummary()) {
    $reviewCount++;
    echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product) ?>
}?>
```

And after the loop is finished, you would have the total number of reviews for the category.  If you need it at the top of the product-list, you could loop through on your own and add custom output:

```
<?php 
$reviews = array();  // this will be populated with the output for products with reviews

foreach ($_productCollection as $_product) {
    if($_product->getRatingSummary()) 
        $reviews[] = $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, 'short');
}
$reviewCount = count($reviews);
?>
```

Comment: This is returning all review from entire website but i needed only reviews to that category from where we load product list.
For an example we have website www.example.com this website has 6 category with 800 products and 300 reviews in total. We have A B C D category. Now we have A category which has 57 review and B ,C,D has rest. So when i click category A it gives all the products it belongs and here i want to display those 57 reviews bottom of product list.